# activate casper-rw partition

Tags: linux, persistence

I've got a "live" LM 18.3X. Added a "casper-rw" partition. Now, I need to get the O.S. to recognize/use that partition.

What file do I go to to change the command lines and what are those changes I must make? I looked at a site that gave instructions for Ubuntu, but haven't found one for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint iso files are similar enough to Ubuntu iso files for **mkusb** to create a persistent live drive with a `casper-rw` partition and prepare 'everything' on the drive for it to work. See the following links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

[mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

This screenshot illustrates a persistent live system, where `aufs` matches `casper-rw`, here at `/dev/sdb5`:

[image]

Edit: The following screenshot illustrates mkusb running in Linux Mint (persistent live created from `linuxmint-18.3-cinnamon-64bit.iso`).

[image]

Comment: I got E: unable to locate package mkusb. Subsequently, all the other commands returned the same E;

Comment: @Rick, Which linux distro and version did you run, when you got 'E: unable to locate package mkusb'? It works for me to install mkusb in Linux Mint via the PPA as described in the answer. See the edited answer with a second screenshot.